# Validating a Cell to become required when another Cell in the same row has a value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

In my form, there are several rows which have two input field. I want to get the required error in quantity cell if the product cell has selected. This should happen for the each and every row. Currently, I have a jquery function which I have used for each and every row separately. I want a single function which can work for every row. Hope someone will help to solve my problem. Thank you.

I have attached my code for the reference

```js
$('#product1').change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() != null ) {
    $('#quantity1').prop('required',true);
  }
});

$('#product2').change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() != null ) {
    $('#quantity2').prop('required',true);
  }
});
$('#product3').change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() != null ) {
    $('#quantity3').prop('required',true);
  }
});
```

```html
                            <tr>

                              <td><select class="form-control select2 error" name="product1" style="width: 100%" id="product1">
                                <option disabled selected value> -- select a Product -- </option>
                                <option value="1"> Product 1 </option>
                                <option value="2"> Product 2 </option>
                                <option value="3"> Product 3 </option>
                               
                              </select>
                            </td>
                            <td><input class="form-control error1" name="quantity1" id="quantity1" type="text" /></td>
                            <td><input  class="form-control" name="freeIssue1" id="freeIssue1" type="text" /></td>
                            <td align="center"><button  class="btn btn-danger" name="close" id="close" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></td>
                          </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td><select class="form-control select2 error" name="product2" style="width: 100%" id="product2">
                              <option disabled selected value> -- select a Product -- </option>
                              <option value="1"> Product 1 </option>
                                <option value="2"> Product 2 </option>
                                <option value="3"> Product 3 </option>
                            </select>
                          </td>
                          <td><input class="form-control error1" name="quantity2" id="quantity2" type="text" /></td>
                          <td><input  class="form-control" name="freeIssue2" id="freeIssue2" type="text" /></td>
                          <td align="center"><button  class="btn btn-danger" name="close" id="close" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></td>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                          <td><select class="form-control select2 error" name="product3" style="width: 100%" id="product3">
                            <option disabled selected value> -- select a Product -- </option>
                            <option value="1"> Product 1 </option>
                                <option value="2"> Product 2 </option>
                                <option value="3"> Product 3 </option>
                          </select>
                        </td>
                        <td><input class="form-control error1" name="quantity3" id="quantity3" type="text" /></td>
                        <td><input  class="form-control" name="freeIssue3" id="freeIssue3" type="text" /></td>
                        <td align="center"><button  class="btn btn-danger" name="close" id="close" onclick="SomeDeleteRowFunction(this)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></button></td>
                      </tr>
```

Comment: Start your mod by using the class and not the id's `$('.select2').change(function () {`

Comment: @RiggsFolly when I use the class I am getting the error message in quantity cell in every row when a particular single product cell is selected.

Comment: So now look up `.next()` in the jquery manual

Comment: @RiggsFolly `$('.select2').change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() != null ) {
    $(this).next('input').prop('required',true);
  }
}); ` I have done this according to your instruction. But couldnt get the proper output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer -- didn't originally notice that you were trying to make a different element required based off of which was selected, which makes way more sense.

```
    $('.productSelect').on('change', function(event){

    var elementID = $(event.target).attr("id");
    var numberPart = elementID.replace("#product", "");

    if ($(event.target).val() != null ) {
        $("#quantity" + numberPart).prop('required', true);
    }
});
```

I changed the class selector, so for this to work you would have to add the 'productSelect' class to your html. Using event.target lets you decipher which element was actually edited and modify it without having to declare a function for every element. I haven't tested this but I think it is probably close to what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But unfortunately, it's not working. I have tried `elementID.split` instead of `elementID.replace` as well. but didn't get an output.

Comment: What happens if you log the value of elementID after it is declared? Also it just ocurred to me that I should have written [replace("product", "");] -- no #

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your support. I have made several small changes and now it is working perfectly fine. I have mentioned the correct solution below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct solution for my problem.

```js
$('.productSelect').change(function() {

  var elementID = $(this).attr("id");
  var numberPart = elementID.split("t", 2);

  if ($(this).val() != null) {
    $('#quantity' + numberPart[1]).prop('required', true);
  }
});
```

Hope this will help someone.